# Python: Como ejecutar una funcion a una cantidad X de archivos (.XML)?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

Necesito ejecutar una funcion en Python a una gran cantidad de archivos .XML. Necesito que la funcion para parsear se ejecute en todos los archivos que terminen en .XML.

Este es un fragmento del codigo para parsear el archivo .XML:

```
import os 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



dirpath = os.getcwd()
file_list = []

for root,_, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):

    for filename in filenames:
        file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for filename in file_list:

    if filename.endswith('.XML'):
```

Hasta este punto me muestra todos los archivos que terminan en .XML, mas no logro descifrar como seria el codigo para que la funcion se ejecute en todos esos archivos.

```
def printXML():

            #Se declaran variables para ubicar los elementos requeridos
            file = ET.parse() #Parsea el documento
            root = pnr.getroot() #Se ubica en la raiz del documento
            loc = root.findall('root') #Busca todos los elementos(childs) de root
            oficina = root.findall('root/child1') #Busca todos los elementos de child1


            #Buscar todos los archivos que terminan en XML


            #A partir de este punto se empiezan a imprimir toda la informacion utilizando for loop


            for lo in loc:
                print 'Localizador:', lo.find(child12).text
                print 'Version:', lo.find(child12).text


            for og in oficina:
                print 'token:', og.find('child21').text
                print 'office', og.find('child22').text
                print 'description', og.find('child23').text

printXML()
```

En este caso solo me muestra en la consola el archivo que extraje del .XML... necesito eso que imprimio realizarlo a todos los archivos XML que esten en X carpeta...

El codigo que coloque anteriormente ya me ubica los archivos, mas no se como comenzar o donde buscar o como iniciar el loop para que ejecute esta funcion a todos los archivos .XML

Comment: Simplemente llamala en el `for` por cada archivo ruta de `file_list`. Puedes guardar cada salida de tu función en una lista por ejemplo, `resultados = [funcion_parseo(ruta) for ruta in file_list if ruta.endswith('.XML') ]`. Necesitariamos ver como implementas la función de parseo o que expliques que quieres hacer o como quieres guardar sus resultados para poder ayudarte mejor. Saludos.

Comment: ya agregue el codigo que parsea el documento, claro no parsea todo el documento solo lo que yo deseo extraer de el.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, tu rutina debiera reescribirse así:

```
def printXML(file):

            #Se declaran variables para ubicar los elementos requeridos
            tree = ET.parse(file) #Parsea el documento
            root = tree .getroot() #Se ubica en la raiz del documento
            loc = root.findall('root') #Busca todos los elementos(childs) de root
            oficina = root.findall('root/child1') #Busca todos los elementos de child1

            for lo in loc:
                print 'Localizador:', lo.find(child12).text
                print 'Version:', lo.find(child12).text

            for og in oficina:
                print 'token:', og.find('child21').text
                print 'office', og.find('child22').text
                print 'description', og.find('child23').text
```

Y tal como te comentó @FJSevilla, el proceso de cada archivo lo harías así:

```
for filename in file_list:
    if filename.endswith('.XML'):
       printXML(filename)
```